# Why does xrdp session manager not show a user password login prompt?

Tags: arch-linux, remote-desktop

What setting do I need to get the **user/password prompt** working?

I installed `xrdp` on a headless system using the following script:

```
# X Window Server
sudo pacman -Sy xorg-server --noconfirm
# Adds Startup scripts in User Folder
sudo pacman -S xorg-xinit --noconfirm
# Desktop Environment
sudo pacman -S xfce4 --noconfirm
# Install Internet Browser
yaourt -S icecat --noconfirm
# Install xrdp
yaourt -S xrdp --noconfirm
# Setup /etc/xdp/startwm.sh
printf "#!/bin/sh\nexec startxfce4" > /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
# Start xrfp
sudo systemctl start xrdp
sudo systemctl start xrdp-sesman
sudo systemctl enable xrdp
sudo systemctl enable xrdp-sesman
```

I want any user to be able to open a connection and arrive at a login screen.

## Why this?

[image]

## And not this?

[image]

## Open Initial Connection with

[image]

---

Notes: `uname -srm` > Linux 4.6.4-1-ARCH x86_64

I can connect to the window manager fine if I provide the proper credentials on the Windows side for the connection. I would like my xrdp server to accept any connection and allow the user to provide credentials at that stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `xrdp.ini` do you have the `autorun` directive set under `[Globals]`?

It may be the case that it's set to autostart a session and this is why it's failing to provide the logon screen. Try removing this entirely and see what happens. If you don't have this set, post the file here and it'll be easier to diagnose.

If you don't have your heart set on `xrdp` and just need a remote desktop solution I would suggest [X2go](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php). The session is done entirely over SSH X11 forwarding and, in my experience, is much more responsive than any of the alternatives. Plus the fact that it's done over SSH is an added bonus security-wise.

Comment: In my `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini` under `[Globals]`, I found `autorun=xrdp2` active. After commenting it out and running `systemctl restart xrdp`, I get the menu. Thanks. 19 hours left and you'll get the bounty if I remember in 19 hours.

Comment: What happens if you remove/comment out that line, restart and connect again?

Comment: Excellent stuff man, glad it's working. I still stubbornly stand by my X2go recommendation though!

Comment: I am stuck working at a company that uses useless Windows in their conference rooms. Thanks for the tip. I would much prefer an SSH tunnel.

Comment: I feel your pain... All the best mate.